# How to match elements of two series by np.array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two series namely train_1 and train_2,

```
import numpy as np
mean = 0
std = 1 
num_samples = 4
train_1 = numpy.random.normal(mean, std, size=num_samples)
train_2 = numpy.random.normal(mean, std, size=num_samples)
```

I am entering this command:

```
X = np.array(train_1,train_2, dtype=float)
```

and taking this output:

```
array([[ 0.82561222,  0.95885746,  0.40454621,  1.37793967],
      [ 0.93473674, -1.51716492, -0.56732792,  1.03333013]])
```

But, I would like these different series to match in ordered manner such this:

```
Y = np.array(([3,5], [5,1], [10,2], [6,1.5]), dtype=float) 
Y
array([[  3. ,   5. ],
       [  5. ,   1. ],
       [ 10. ,   2. ],
       [  6. ,   1.5]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding your question, but is this not simply the transpose?

```
X = np.array(train_1,train_2, dtype=float).T
```

Note the `.T` at the end. In this case `X` will have two columns, the first will be `train_1`, the second will be `train_2`.

Comment: @Cenk, no problem. If this answered your question please mark it as "accepted", which is the tick under the vote arrows.